# Object type column with percentages shown with % and in decimal, convert all to decimal

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df:

```
   Percentage Purchased
0  50.00%     0
1  66.37%     1
2  50.00%     0
3  0.5        1
4  0.5000     1
```

'Percentage' is object type, I want my end result to be:

```
   Percentage Purchased
0  0.5000     0
1  0.6637     1
2  0.5000     0
3  0.5000     1
4  0.5000     1
```

Ive tried using:

```
df['Percentage'] = dataset['Percentage'].str.replace(r'%', r'').astype('float')/100
```

To first get the percentages into floats, then just convert the whole df into float, but ***the problem is that the above code replaces the fields that already have '0.5' / 0.5000 with NaN***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) for convert all values with no percentage to floats, unparseable values are `NaN`s, so possible repace them by `Series` created by [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) - solution working if data contains only percentage and non percentage numbers:

```
s = df['Percentage'].str.replace(r'%', r'').astype('float')/100
df['Percentage']  = pd.to_numeric(df['Percentage'], errors='coerce').fillna(s)
print (df)
   Percentage  Purchased
0      0.5000          0
1      0.6637          1
2      0.5000          0
3      0.5000          1
4      0.5000          1
```

Another solution with list comprehension or `apply` with test if percentage in values:

```
df['Percentage'] = [float(x.replace('%', ''))/100 
                    if '%' in x 
                    else float(x) for x in df['Percentage']]
```

---

```
f = lambda x: float(x.replace('%', ''))/100 if '%' in x else float(x)
df['Percentage'] = df['Percentage'].apply(f)

print (df)
   Percentage  Purchased
0      0.5000          0
1      0.6637          1
2      0.5000          0
3      0.5000          1
4      0.5000          1
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help :

```
df['Percentage'] = df.Percentage.apply(lambda x: format(float(x.split('%')[0]), '.4f'))
print(df)

     Percentage  Purchased
0      0.5000          0
1      0.6637          1
2      0.5000          0
3      0.5000          1
4      0.5000          1
```